# Reload records in Select - jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

At this time I have a select in rails with simple form this way

```
            <%= f.association :tipo,
                :label => false,
                :required => true,
                :input_html => {:class => 'span2', :onChange => "recargarS2(this.value)"}
```

And I want to make a code, I guess in the event click or onchange
Then I want when I clicked in that select with Jquery find again all the records in the table(tipos) and show it in the select

I have find in a lots of websites but o haven't find the solution

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english is not my native language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use AJAX.

A little example **using jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/select/something/" // the URL that user will be request the information
                             // from database.
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); // shows in console the returned data from URL.
   };
});
```

To learn more about AJAX, [take a look here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I dont know what happend but i doesn't work

I have the view like that
<%= f.association :tipo,
:label => false,
:required => true,
:input_html => {:class => 'span2', :onFocus => "recargarS2()"}

And the Javascript is this way
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    google.load("jquery", "1.2", {uncompressed:true});
    function recargarS2(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/tipos/index.html.erb"
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data); // shows in console the returned data from URL.
            };
        });
    }
</script>
What else i need to do?

Comment: What appears on console when you run `recargarS2()` function?

Comment: Doesn't Appear anything, so this is not calling the function, but why :/

Comment: What `/tipos/index.html.erb/` is returning?

Comment: Not, Is not returning anything, in the console doesn't appear anything either, what i need is just when i clicked on the select show all the records of the table(tipos), because i add records with another function without updating the view

Comment: My question was: when you access `/tipos/index.html/erb/` what you receive?